# returned value from the web service in soap is coming only half the string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, soap

i am calling a web service using SOAP and web service is returning one string that string should be like this `"test/Workspace\xxx2\qualityinaction.xxx\wwwroot\party name-hotel"`

but returned string contains only `"test/Workspace\xxx2\qualityinaction.xxx\wwwroot\"`
(Locally i have tested that web service its returning the full path but not giving when we call through iphone using SOAP)
party name-hotel--- this is trimmed from that string  why is it so,,,SOAP wont return the string which has Blank spaces??

can any one help me ,,,,,thanx in advance

Comment: Did you try logging the contents of the response on the iOS device? It would be helpful you posted how that string was stored and how you are trying to parse it. XPath? NSXmlParser? Substring? TouchXML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use urlencode/urldecode as the string contains the space. 
if you want to test just this scenario space is get replaced by %20 .. if you do party%20name-hotel. it should work.

http://www.bagonca.com/blog/2009/04/08/iphone-tip-1-url-encoding-in-objective-c/